# How to efficiently edit massive amounts of data

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is an example dataset. Let me show everyone what I am doing to my data and then I will explain what I am struggling with. I apologize if the title isn't an accurate description. I tried my best but I am a bit new at this. Feel free to change it to something more suiting if needed

```
Location sample1 sample 2 sample 3
chr1:1234 0/1 1/1 0/0
chr2:5678 0/0 0/0 0/0
chr3:2345 1/1 1/1 1/1
chr4:6789 0/1 1/1 ./.
```

I use this to convert them to either a YES, NO, or MAYBE

```
replacement<-function(x){
  x=replace(x,which(x=='./.'),0.1) 
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0/0'),0)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0/1'),1)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='1/1'),2)
}

test=apply(test.data.set,2,replacement)

test.data.2 <- as.data.frame(test)

replacement<-function(x){
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0.1'), "MAYBE") 
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0'), "NO")
  x=replace(x,which(x=='1'), "YES")
  x=replace(x,which(x=='2'), "YES")
}

test.data.3=apply(test.data.2,2,replacement)

test.data.4 <- as.data.frame(test.data.3)
```

Dataset after running

```
Location sample1 sample 2 sample 3
chr1:1234 YES YES NO
chr2:5678 NO NO NO
chr3:2345 YES YES YES
chr4:6789 YES YES MAYBE
```

So what I wrote above currently works for me. However, I have a new dataset that contains about 300 samples (columns) and about.. I'm not even sure, easily 500 million rows, so I need to alter over a billion "cells". I tried running this on a cluster with 256G with of memory and it just times out. I know what I wrote above is far from the "smoothest" way of altering my data. Does anyone have suggestions to streamline this process? I feel like dplyr has to have some kind of way to do this.

Any help would be amazing! Feel free to ask any questions if you need clarifications.

Comment: I think you are missing `MAYBE` in your 2nd replacement function

Comment: Why don't you just go from the original `0/1` type data straight to the NO and YES data? Why the intermediate step?

Comment: Sorry @prosoitos that was a typo! Fixed it

Comment: @JohnPaul I could do that but I doesn't even get past the first part so cutting out that step would help but still wouldn't finish

Comment: And if you use `dplyr::case_when` you don't have to create a function and can apply the change directly

Comment: Could you provide some data (for instance with `dput()`) so that we could play with it without having to create it on our end? I can show you how to use `case_when`

Comment: @prosoitos I'm not quite sure how to use that. Let me look up how to use `dput()` and I will get back to you. `case_when` looks great though!!

Comment: That's ok. I recreated your data already and will put something in a bit. But yes: do look up `dput()` for your next SO question

Comment: @prosoitos  Thank you so much!! I will continue to read up on `dput()` so people in future won't have to do that for me. I appreciate the help! I am interested to see wrote.

Comment: @Brian - just do `dput(head(test))`

Comment: @fugu Thanks for the suggestion. The dataset if about 50 gigs so it takes a while to load into R. The cluster I use removes all loaded data after the script is completed. Then you have to wait in line to use it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Recreate your data:

```
df <- tibble(
  Location = letters[1:4],
  sample1 = c("0/1", "0/0", "1/1", "0/1"),
  sample2 = c("1/1", "0/0", "1/1", "1/1"),
  sample3 = c("0/0", "0/0", "1/1", "./.")
)
```

Code:

```
df %>% mutate_at(
  vars(- Location),
  funs(case_when(
    . == "1/1" | . == "0/1" ~ "YES",
    . == "0/0" ~ "NO",
    . == "./." ~ "MAYBE"
  ))
)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Location sample1 sample2 sample3
  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 a        YES     YES     NO     
2 b        NO      NO      NO     
3 c        YES     YES     YES    
4 d        YES     YES     MAYBE
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It took me a bit to get a subdataset to test this one. Works great. I am going to put it to the test later today!